# How do I manage library dependencies used by the micro service architecture?

Tags: microservices, system-design

*My english isn't good. so if you don't understand, please let me know.*

I designed micro service architecture. Each service has same library which is team mate made.

(Theses libraries are already distributed maven system, and we used versioning.)

I wonder how to manage these common library dependency (version). Sometimes if library version changed, we have to check all of services and upgrade dependecies.

So someone said to me. 
`Try to make common library which has all library dependency, than other services use that common library.`

But i don't like these idea. 
Is this best for micro service architecture?

**How do I manage library dependencies used by the micro service architecture?**

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using packaging

The answer is simple: Packaging. There are multiple tools out there that help you package your libraries into some format that is reusable between your projects.

1. You can use npm in the javascript world
2. You can use nuget primarily in the .net world
3. You can use maven/artifactory primarily in the java world

The list goes on. The concept and the ideas are the same.

#### Beware of misusing microservices

Bear in mind the following, though. One of the strengths of microservices, is that individual teams can work on their own microservice using any technology they like and any framework. Most companies drop this way of thinking though as they can't afford to have so many people knowing so many frameworks over time. It needs some thinking though, if the team is big enough and the domain is large enough to warrant microservices.

Second thing is why use common libraries at all? Apart from simple utilities, microservices are not even supposed to call the same databases. Check if you are sharing resources apart from external sdks that call the same apis and such.

#### Backwards compatibility via semantic versioning

If even after minimizing the dependencies you still need some package, then semantic versioning is the key. You must decide between the following

Backwards compatibility and impact.

In semantic versioning we are maintaining versions of the same software until we don't. By using x.y.z versions in your packages and maintaining branches at least four each major, you can support multiple consumers with minimal impact. Downside to this is that you must support multiple versions.

Update in x (major version), means breaking compatibility.

Update in y, means extending the library but maintaining compatibility.

Updated in a, means just bug fixing, plus performance improvements.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The library is already distributed in maven. What I'm wondering is that every microservice needs to be modified when changing the library version. what is best idea for micro service architecture?

Comment: Semantic versioning

Comment: We already used semantic versioning. but team mate told me "Our service is so numerous, let's create a new module to manage all versions, rather than modify all services." i don't like these idea, But I have insufficient grounds to support my opinion.

Comment: Use microservices if you want to minimize dependencies. Create a full module and you are back to monolithic approach. Don't go down that way as you'll be getting the worst out of two worlds. It seems to me that you are missing in design. Check DDD to help you identify the domains and you'll be able to break down to truly individual microservices with minimum inter dependencies.

Comment: thank you! I'll have to study more harder....;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have a common library and maintain it at one place. It should be backward compatible so that it won't impact the dependant services whenever there is a change.

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/06/13/code-reuse-in-microservices-architecture.html is a nice blogpost that explains code reuse in microservices